# Sequence of or and and in if block not working correctly

Tags: java, if-statement, operators, relational

```
 CCMT c = new CCMT();
 c.ccd = null;
Optional<String> cType = Optional.ofNullable(ccmtRequest).map(CCMT::getCcd).map(MOEH::getDestCtry);         

System.out.println(cType.isPresent()); // false
    
if(cType.isPresent() && cType.get().equalsIgnoreCase("CCMT") || cType.get().equalsIgnoreCase("CCWC")) {
  System.out.println("wfegr");
}
```

**ERROR**: Exception **NoSuchElementException**

> Why cType.get() statement is being executed even though first
> condition is **false** itself?

Comment: It **is** working correctly. You just have to use parenthesis in the right places

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).
Writing `A && B || C` is the same as writing `(A && B) || C`.

So in your case you need need to add parentheses around the `||` operator:

```java
if (cType.isPresent() && (cType.get().equalsIgnoreCase("CCMT") || cType.get().equalsIgnoreCase("CCWC"))) {
    System.out.println("wfegr");
}
```

But using more methods of the `Optional` API may be more suited:

```java
cType
    .filter(t -> t.equalsIgnoreCase("CCMT") || t.equalsIgnoreCase("CCWC"))
    .ifPresent(t -> System.out.println("wfegr"));
```